# Blind leading the blind

Tags: discussion

What's the site policy when someone is trying to do something that should not be done because it's really bad practice. Do you answer how to do it or do you explain why it's bad and offer the correct approach?

I'm wondering following this question : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/47161777?iemail=1&noredirect=1

Comment: I'd offer the correct approach. Obviously, it depends on the question.